# FTP is connect but directory is not displaying

Tags: networking, ftp, cpanel

I have 2 network connections. one is "idea" and another is "Reliance". When i use idea then it working very well but when i am using Reliance internet connection then it showing timeout error.

```
Status: Resolving address of royaleimpex.in
Status: Connecting to 208.91.198.76:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Resolving address of royaleimpex.in
Status: Connecting to 208.91.198.76:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Response:   220-You are user number 5 of 150 allowed.
Response:   220-Local time is now 10:01. Server port: 21.
Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
Response:   220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 5 minutes of inactivity.
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   234 AUTH TLS OK.
Status: Initializing TLS...
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Please help.

Comment: If possible a problem with firewall and Server FTP configuration. Server hos not setup FTP server with Passive Port Ranges or his firewalll (server firewall) not properly setup for permissive passive firewalls.

Answer (score 0):

```
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

These errors can happen for a multitude of reasons, but yours is being that your `Reliance` Internet connection isn't fast enough, and FileZilla is timing out before the server can fully send the TLS certificate